# PHP garbage collection: why is this object still referenced

Tags: php, reference, garbage-collection

I just read the manual's page on [Objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

I am using a 3rd party library that executes a callback I provide when the library is done with an object.  In the callback I'd like to unlink the object in memory so the garbage collector (CG) can clean it.

```
function onDone($object){
    // do stuff
    unset($object);
}
```

This doesn't unset the object in the calling code's context. I understand that this is because `$object` in the function is just another copy of the reference to the data in memory. Unsetting that copy leaves the original reference intact. So I made a change:

```
function onDone(&$object){
    //do stuff
    unset($object);
}
```

Through passing-by-reference `&`, I thought the `unset` would actually cut off the only link to the data, freeing the GC to clean it up.  That's not the case; the data is still accessible (see demo).  Why is that?

**[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/hF0tP)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR;

The short answer is that references are merely a way for two variables to share the same value and `unset()` only deletes a variable, not a value. The key thing to remember here is that variables have values, while references *link* values, not variables.

## The Long and Long of It...

First, understanding how PHP removes objects from memory...

Objects are only removed from memory when the **last** reference to that object is deleted. When I say *reference* I don't mean the same thing as [references](http://php.net/language.references) in PHP, like the one you're describing here in the pass-by-reference example. Instead, *any* variable that is assigned the object, is considered something that *references* this object. As such PHP will not remove the object from memory as long as this is true.

Because you create the object outside of the function, then call the function, there are now two places that reference the same object. One is the global variable that instantiated the object. The second is the local variable, in your function, that's using the object. Pass-by-reference or assign-by-reference has no bearing on this behavior, whatsoever, because it's a totally different thing.

When you create an object in PHP, and assign it to a variable, the variable does not store the object itself. Instead, it stores a unique handle that points to the object in memory. The object is stored in an object store, that only PHP has direct control over. This is by design, because PHP manages memory for you. It does not expect you to understand or have to care about, how memory is allocated or freed. It tries to manage memory for you as efficiently as possible, through these abstractions.

So in the following code the object `Foo` is not really deleted until after we get to the last line of this example.

```
class Foo { }

$foo = new Foo; // Object is initialized and stored in memory

$fooCopy = $foo; // The same object handle is copied to $fooCopy

bar($foo);

function bar($foo) {
    unset($foo); // object is still in memory
}


baz($foo);

function baz(&$foo) {
    unset($foo); // object is still in memory
}


$foo->quix = 1; // object is still in memory

unset($foo); // object is still in memory because $fooCopy is still a reference

$fooCopy->quix++;

var_dump($fooCopy->quix); // int(2)

unset($fooCopy); // object is now deleted because last reference is gone
```

As you can see from this example there is a very good reason why PHP won't delete the object in these functions or even when we do `unset($foo)`, because otherwise, by the time we get to the last few lines of this script, this code would not work as we expect it. The object would be freed prematurely. PHP just assumes that since you still have *at least* one variable pointing to the object, that you might still need to use it somewhere down the line. So it does not free it until it reaches a point where nothing points to that object (i.e. nothing can use it).

### Ref Counted GC

This is called ref-counted GC. In principle, each time some variable points to the same place in memory, the ref-count is incremented. Each time a variable is deleted, the ref count to that memory is decremented. Once the ref-count reaches `0`, then, **and only then**, will the memory be marked for garbage collection, and eventually cleaned up by the garbage collector. So in the example above, the variable `$foo` creates a ref-count of `1` to the object `Foo`, that's stored in memory. The variable `$fooCopy` increments that ref-count to `2`. At the point we call the function `bar()` the ref-count is at `3`. By the time we `unset()` or return from `bar()` the ref count goes back down to `2`. Same thing with `baz()`, up to `3` and then down to `2` again. At the point we `unset($foo)` the ref-count is still `1`. PHP will not delete the object. Finally, we reach `unset($fooCopy)` and the ref-count is now `0`. Same thing would happen if the script just ended. PHP would implicitly just clean up all memory.

### Why `unset()` on references doesn't work with Objects

To answer your question, specifically, about why using pass-by-reference and calling `unset()` on the object doesn't work, or doesn't remove the last reference to the object we actually have to explain a bit more about how references actually work in PHP by contrast to objects.

```
$obj = new stdClass;

foo($obj);

function foo(&$obj) {
    unset($obj);
}

var_dump($obj); // this is still here
```

A reference, in PHP, is a way of having two variables share the same value. But an object, is not stored inside of a variable in PHP. Instead, all that is stored is the handle that points to that object (i.e. another level of indirection). So by using pass-by-reference, all you've managed to accomplish is have two different variables share the same object handle. By deleting one of these variables you're still left with the other variable pointing to that handle. So the ref count is still at 1 regardless of which variable you delete.

Now, if you were to re-assign either variable the value `null`, then the one and only handle pointing to that object is now lost, and as such PHP *will* remove the object.

```
$obj = new stdClass;

foo($obj);

function foo(&$obj) {
    $obj = null;
}

var_dump($obj); // this is now null and the object is gone
```

Try to think of it like this. The thing that's actually assigned to `$obj`, both in the local variable, and global variable, is just the object's handle, which is the thing that points to the object itself. So all `unset($obj)` inside this function does is delete the local variable. Deleting one does not delete both.

[image: php object memory]

By assigning a value to a variable, that's a reference to another variable, however, you get the same value in both places.

[image: php object memory references]

Remember, `unset($obj)` inside the function, only deletes the local variable and breaks the reference. It does not delete the object, because the variable outside of the function still continues to reference the handle.

Comment: Above and beyond @Sherif.  The part about *Ref counted GC* is what clicked for me.  One more thing: consider  `$a=$b` vs `$a=&$b`.  In the first case, we are telling PHP that the variables should point to the same object, but have independent handles. So if I later do `$b=$c`, `$a` and `$b` will be different right?  In the 2nd case, we're telling PHP that the variables should share the same handle. So if I later do `$b=$c`, `$a`, `$b` and `$c` will be the same. Right?

Comment: Yes, and no. Objects are little trickier, because they have that extra layer of indirection. The handle is the same regardless of using `$a = &$b` vs `$a = $b`. The handle just points to the object in the object store. However, the value of the handle can be copied around to different variables. The difference is that `$a = $b` will not cause `$b = null` to change the value of `$a`, because it's a different copy of the same handle. But in `$a = &$b` it's the same copy of the same handle. If one variables loses the handle, so does the other.

Comment: Try to think of this the same way you would a book mark in a book. If we each have a book mark and place each of our bookmarks on the same page in the same book, we both know where the information is. If I remove my book mark, yours is still there (but they both point to the same page). However, if we both share just one book mark and I happen to remove that book mark, you lose your place too.

Comment: So after `$a = &$b`, when I do `unset($b)`, all I'm doing is dissociating `$b` from the bookmark. Since `$a` is still bound to it, PHP will not garbage collect the data on the bookmarked page.  On the other hand, if I do `$b=null`, I'm moving the shared bookmark to a `NULL` address, and, since neither variable is referring to the data on the page, garbage collection can take place.

Comment: Right, that would be a more accurate way to describe it. In my analogy you and I are the variables and the book mark is the object handle that we carry with us. Deleting me, does not cause you to lose the book mark, when we share one bookmark, because I'm forced to leave it behind (this is `is_ref` vs. `refcount` semantics in the engine). So, the same thing goes the other way around. `$a = &$b; unset($a); // still not gced`.